# How to apply base2 logarithm to an RDD of Ints in Spark?

Tags: logging, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd, logarithm

What is the proper way of doing this to apply log2 to my RDD of numbers? Is there a function to help with this?

Comment: See this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDD:

```
import org.apache.commons.math.util.MathUtils

val rdd: RDD[Double] = ???
rdd.map(x => MathUtils.log(2.0, x))
```

DataFrame:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.log2

rdd.toDF("value").select(log2("value"))
```