# How to take the logarithm of an RDD in Spark (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logarithm

How do I take the logarithm of an RDD? I have a `val rdd: RDD[Double]` and I simply want to take the logarithm of it.

This is essentially the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812622/how-to-apply-base2-logarithm-to-an-rdd-of-ints-in-spark), but the solution proposed does not work. I run:

```
val rdd: RDD[Double] = <something>
val log_y = rdd.map(x => org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Log(2.0, x))
```

and I get the error:

```
error: object org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Log is not a value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see, this class from **math3** computes the natural log function and it works like:

```
new org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Log().value(3)
res1: Double = 1.0986122886681098
```

It is the version that comes with the Spark 3.1.2.

```
val log_y = rdd.map(x => org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.function.Log().value)
```

If you are using this same version

This is the code of this class:

```
public class Log implements UnivariateDifferentiableFunction, DifferentiableUnivariateFunction {
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public double value(double x) {
        return FastMath.log(x);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc}
     * @deprecated as of 3.1, replaced by {@link #value(DerivativeStructure)}
     */
    @Deprecated
    public UnivariateFunction derivative() {
        return FunctionUtils.toDifferentiableUnivariateFunction(this).derivative();
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc}
     * @since 3.1
     */
    public DerivativeStructure value(final DerivativeStructure t) {
        return t.log();
    }

}
```

As you can see, you need to create an instance and then the **value** property is what actually executes the log function. Although you could create an instance outside the map and mark it as **transient** to avoid creating a new instance per RDD element. Or you can use this class in a mapPartition function to create only an instance per partition.

Comment: why is the .value needed here? I have seen that elsewhere but did not think needed here.